# no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument list

Tags: c++

```
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument list
```

I'm getting this error when try to compile, how can i fix this? post the code cus it's better to understand then photo.
So this is the error that i'm getting i don't have any idea what is causing this and how to fix.

```
int MakeWindows();
int CloseWindows();

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{

   HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
   const char* cHWID = "{1234-5678-9669-1337}"; //


   if (GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL) }
        printf("Hardware ID: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);

        if (strstr(hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid, cHWID)) {
           printf("Your hardware ID was successful\n\n");
           Sleep(3069);
           system("CLS");

        }
        else {
             printf("Your Hardware ID was denied;\n");
             Sleep(1000);
             TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL);
        }
    }
    else {
         return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: It is advisable to share the code text other than a screenshot of your code. Kindly share your code in text here.

Comment: ready code posted

Comment: strstr expects two parameters of const char*. hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid returns a CHAR  szHwProfileGuid[HW_PROFILE_GUIDLEN]; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-hw_profile_infoa

Comment: This might help too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

`strstr` wants a `char*` as its first arg. `szHwProfileGuid` is going to be a wide string. You need `wccstr`

So try :

`const wcchar* cHWID = L"{1234-5678-9669-1337}";`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be wccstr see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-hw_profile_infoa, is CHAR defined as wccstr?

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from your project being compiled as Unicode ('wide' characters, usually `wchar_t` types or defined in Windows as `WCHAR`), and you also using single-byte characters (`char` or `CHAR`), for example in your call to [`strstr`()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

(As you're seeing here, the two don't cooperate nicely!)

The Windows API defines two versions of many of its structures (and therefore the respective functions that use them), one to accommodate each character type.  In your code example, `HW_PROFILE_INFO` is actually defined as `HW_PROFILE_INFOW` for the wide-character version of the API, and you're invoking `GetCurrentHwProfileW`().  This is fine and by design, since your build is instrumented as a Unicode build.

There are a few ways you could fix this; here's a simple method (your original code with two slight modifications):

```
int MakeWindows();
int CloseWindows();

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{

   HW_PROFILE_INFOA hwProfileInfo;  // <== Change # 1
   const char* cHWID = "{1234-5678-9669-1337}"; //


   if (GetCurrentHwProfileA(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL) }  // <== Change # 2
        printf("Hardware ID: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);

        if (strstr(hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid, cHWID)) {
           printf("Your hardware ID was successful\n\n");
           Sleep(3069);
           system("CLS");

        }
        else {
             printf("Your Hardware ID was denied;\n");
             Sleep(1000);
             TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL);
        }
    }
    else {
         return 0;
    }
};
```

This set of simple changes has you explicitly using the single-byte versions of the WINAPI functions, keeping your call to [`strstr`()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) consistent for its two arguments.

(I'll mention again that this is only one way to fix this problem, and the "best" solution may be subjective. :))

Comment: can i add in maincpp?

Comment: Sure, just edit your original file and add the `A` each place :)

Comment: See lines where I commented `Change # 1` and `Change # 2`.

Comment: oh yeah, but i just want to know how can i add in maincpp i mean where exactly

Comment: Same as where you compiled and got your original error.

Comment: i want to set the hwid of an pc on the dll, so other pc can't use that dll

Comment: That sounds like a different problem with a different question :)

Comment: i replace my code for your code and give me one error, " identifier "_In_HINSTANCE" is undefined

Comment: Getting closer!  You need a space between `_In_` and `HINSTANCE` (note how the other parameters to your `WinMain`() function are separated).  Will update my answer for completeness.